# Apache / MySql is not running. What is wrong?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, ulimit

I installed lampp / xampp on my Ubuntu 12.04. After installing, Apache and MySQL were running properly. Now, they're not. Here's what I get when I try to run apache:

Command:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Result:

```
* Starting web server apache2 
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: everytime you get an error that contains `Permission denied`, try prepending the command `sudo` to it. :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you forgot the `sudo`:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

The better way to start apache (or any other init.d service) is:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: ha thanks! I did forget the sudo! It's working now - I'm learning PHP ;)

Comment: @Valerlu if you found it useful, please mark it as answer. :)